# Error: "Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable" después de actualizar pandas a 1.4.0, ¿Cómo resolverlo?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, depuración, spyder

No estoy seguro sí este es un problema común con el ambiente `Spyder` después de actualizar manualmente una librería desde el `cmd` pero, en mi caso, actualizé la librería `Pandas` a `1.4.0` con `cmd`, antes de eso todo funcionaba de maravilla, pero después de hacerlo, mi ambiente `Spyder` arrojó el siguiente error la intentar mostrar una simple `df`:

[image]

El código que ejecuté fue:

```
import pandas as pd

#nombres de columna
column_names = ["Time", "Currency", "Volatility expected", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous"]

#crea una df con los nombres de columna
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

Es importante mencionar que sí escribo `df` en la consola de Spyder, SÍ OBTENGO la información almacenada en la variable `df`:

[image]

Mi único problema es que no puedo ver los detalles de esa variable cuando le doy click a ella en el `Explorador de Variables` de Spyder

¿Hay alguna solución que pueda aplicar además de desinstalar Spyder y volverlo a instalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que [mi problema será resuelto al final de este mes](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17342).

Por ende, me tocó desactualizar la version de Pandas a `1.3.5` usando `pip install -Iv --user pandas==1.3.5` en `cmd`, y `conda install pandas==1.3.5` en mi ambiente `miniconda3`

Hecho esto, ya se arregló de nuevo el explorador de variables:

[image: solucionado]